# Vb.net deployment to other machine with mysql localhost as Database

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I want to deploy my VB.NET Application on other machine, im using mysql database and this is my Connection: [Connection String](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hfw1C.png)
my problem is when i open the application to other machine it says "Unable To Connect To Specified MySQL Hosts" what seem to be the problem here? im really new at this, sorry for my bad english, and thank you in advance.

Comment: is MySQL installed and running on the target machine?

Comment: i installed mysql server on the other machine and tried to run my application but i just got a message that my db was unknown.

Comment: i know i can fix it by re doing my db on other machines but, that would be a problem cause im going to deploy this on several machines, and it will cost m a lot of work, is there other way to deploy my app without doing that?

Comment: well your installation process could include something to deploy the database (e.g. a .sql dump of the db structure, and a command to run it into mysql). But it depends on the real intention - should each instance of the application have its own separate instance of the database? Or should they share the same central database, so that data is shared between all the copies of the application?

Comment: You need to include some details on your setup, as well as what you have already tried. Do you have MYSQL set up on a webserver so that all of your machines can access the database? Can you ping the MYSQL server from the machine that you are trying to connect to it?

Comment: @ADyson well in my debug folder i can see a file called (Mydatabasename.PDB) does this file help?

Comment: @GavinPerkins does MYSQL webserver accessible even without internet connection?

Comment: A PDB file is related to your .NET code, nothing to do with MySQL. The fact it shares the same name as your database is a coincidence presumably because you gave your VB project the same name. Are you able to answer my question about how your program is intended to be used (database-per-install or shared data accessible to all users)?

Comment: @ADyson it's actually okay if it's database-per-install, would be better if share data

Comment: ok so if shared data is better, then don't worry about installing the database at all. Put the database once onto a server where all the machines can access it (if all machines are on the same network, then it's easy). Then in your connection string change "localhost" to the name of the server. Then you can deploy exactly the same application to every machine with the same settings. They will connect to the database on the remote server.

Comment: how about if it's database-per-install, cause ill be using the application on different machines on different places, and it would be a work to do if im going to add a database every place the it should be installed

Comment: huh? You just said you preferred shared data, and also doing it the shared data way will be **less** work

Comment: i just want my application to be plug and play application, install my application to every pc with a database, so i can just give it to the client without a problem

Comment: yes...but you are describing two **entirely different** usage scenarios. One where each PC has its own database, so data is **not shared** between PCs. And one where all PCs share the same data. You say you don't mind which structure you use, and yet this is a **critical** design point and entirely changes the way your application will work. You need to decide the purpose of the application - does each instance stand by itself, with no contact with the others, or is it a tool to allow people to work together and share the same data?

Comment: can't i just deploy my application with a stand alone database in it?

Comment: yes you can. but it's quite unusual. Normally the reason for a database is to share data among different users who are on different PCs. So the most common situation is one central database and multiple copies of the application. That's why I was asking if you if you are certain that a standalone database is really what you want. If you're sure, then go ahead. But you seemed unsure what you were doing, so I asked.

Comment: i guess it should be stand alone cause i have an export to excel button on that application which deletes all the data on the database and transfer it to excel, it would be better if it has a different Database pero Machine

Comment: Doing an export destroys all the data in the database? That's very unusual as well. I would be fascinated to know the purpose of this application.

Comment: it's just an export to excel button with a truncate function, and import to return all the data

Comment: no I meant the overall purpose of the .net application. but it's just out of interest. We've gone a long way from the original question!

Comment: yes, so any ideas on how my application work on other machine with a database, or somehow at least a code to run a MYSQL Workbench schema script on my application

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to set up your MySQL database on one of the free MySQL server sites that are out there (I think I used hostgator when I first played around with this). If you do this you should be able to connect from anywhere.

Comment: i have no experience in using a webhost, but my question is, in the webhost all im going to put is my db?

Comment: You'll put your db there, then as long as your connection string works on your dev machine, it should work anywhere with web access.

Comment: so do i need to make a simple website for it or just db?

Comment: No need to make a website, just put your db on it.